Correct usage of Range.overlaps in SQLModel/SQLAlchemy
I have the following code:
overlapping: Sequence[Booking] = (
    await session.exec(
        select(Booking)
        .join(Apartment)
        .join(User)
        .where(
            Range(
                lower=booking.end_date,
                upper=booking.cleaning_deadline,
                bounds="[]",
            ).overlaps(Range(Booking.end_date, Booking.cleaning_deadline))
        )
    )
).all()

It produces this output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/home/jakov/Projects/intis/src/web/server.py", line 120, in import_calendar
    ).overlaps(Range(Booking.end_date, Booking.cleaning_deadline))
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jakov/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/intis-I4I4liA8-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/ranges.py", line 381, in overlaps
    self._compare_edges(slower, slower_b, olower, olower_b) >= 0
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jakov/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/intis-I4I4liA8-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/ranges.py", line 274, in _compare_edges
    if value1 < value2:  # type: ignore
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jakov/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/intis-I4I4liA8-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 3938, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Boolean value of this clause is not defined")
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined

Basically I want to do this query via the ORM:
select * from booking b where (b.end_date , b.cleaning_deadline) overlaps (?, ?);

I've tested it on the database and it works, but I cannot get SQLAlchemy to do what I want it to do.
